# Codeigniter session values lost on redirect MacOS

Tags: php, macos, codeigniter, session, iframe

I have an online application which has been running for couple of years
Codeigniter 3.1.11, PHP 7.2
I have added an online feature for clients so they can use it on their website by using an iframe

```
<iframe src="https://www.mywebsite.com/client/login" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" id="fileframe"></iframe>
```

Everything works fine on Windows platform or android OS, but under MacOS it seems that session values are lost when the page is redirected

```
redirect('client/index', 'refresh');
```

If I display the view directly then the session values are kept, but unfortunately, I have to use the redirect method

```
$this->load->view('client/index', $this->data);
```

Here is the config part which might be useful to know

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/; SameSite=None';
$config['cookie_secure']    = TRUE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
```

And here is what session looks like after login and before the redirect page

```
Array
(
    [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1628374247
    [logged_in] => 1
    [csid] => 16196
    [csname] => customer
    [clname] => client
    [clid] => 115
)
```

And this is what the session after the redirect page

```
Array
(
    [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1628374247
    [logged_in] => 
)
```

When a page is loaded, there will be validation on some of the session values, once I try to login using Mac Pro or IPhone with both Safari or Chrome, it redirects back to the login page as the session values already lost. As I mentioned before, same exact code works fine on Windows and Android OS!
If I try to login directly from my website not via client's website "iframe", it works fine using MacOS on both Safari and Chrome.
I am not sure why MacOS behave this way when an iframe used to embed another website!
Any feedback or suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: how does the session config look like? could you please update your question?

Comment: @Vickel, I am using the default CI sessions, I have added the session variables.

Comment: this is just a guess, since I have no macos device to doublecheck: try `$config['sess_driver'] = 'database'; $config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';` It could be a confused session driver file system... it's working for me, but again never checked in an iframe with a mac

Comment: @Vickel, thanks for your comment, I was trying to avoid using database sessions and hoping that someone else might had the same issue! I will try to test it with database sessions on my Dev Server, not sure if changing to database sessions require any changes to session manipulation as I never used it before and don't want any mishaps on Production app!

Comment: just read through the session's docs, specially [Session drivers](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html?highlight=session#session-drivers).  It's easy to implement and worth a try!

Comment: unfortunately, changing to database did not make any difference as it still redirect back to the login page even though I can see the session id in the ci_session table, I am sure it is something to do with iframe implementation as for some reason MacOS clear the session when it detects two different domains? but then the session id is kept intact only the values are cleared?